# Different ways of applying multiple view models in single view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have seen two ways of binding multiple view model in a single view as far as I am learning Knockout. My question here is:

1. Is there advantage of using way 1 or way 2?
2. In which situation one way is chosen over another?
3. Any other better way of binding multiple view model in single view?

```js
// Way 1
masterVM = {
    viewModelA : new viewModelA(),
    viewModelB : new viewModelB(),
    viewModelC : new viewModelC(),
}

// Way 2
ko.applyBindings(viewModelA, document.getElementById('#div1'))
ko.applyBindings(viewModelB, document.getElementById('#div2'))
ko.applyBindings(viewModelC, document.getElementById('#div3'))
```

Comment: `complexity` of your application makes you to choose b/w 1 or 2 .

Comment: @supercool appreciate if you could explain in further detail

Comment: If you have multiple independently-modeled sections, you probably ought to make them components. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering out of order...

> 2. In which situation one way is chosen over another?

That's a matter context, size of your application, seperating and composing concerns in a logical mannar, as well as taste. Amongst others.

> 1. Is there advantage of using way 1 or way 2?

No big differences. Approach 1 requires you to construct all first level sub viewmodels or at least know what they'll be before you can start doing applyBindings.

> 3. Any other better way of binding multiple view model in single view?

As mentioned in the comments, you could have a look at components, but I personally consider that more something for widgets and reusable controls, not whole areas of your application.